# can't get files that are dropped into dropzone

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to do drag and drop image upload, but i can't get files that are dropped into dropzone.

```js
$(function(){

 $('.dropzone').on('drop', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer); // this returns empty dataTransfer object.
 });

 $('.dropzone').on('dragover', function(e){
  $(this).addClass('active');
  return false;
 });

 $('.dropzone').on('dragleave', function(e){
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  return false;
 });

}());
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? 'Can't get files' doesn't explain much. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: already found solution. I couldn't get those files which i dropped into droppezone.dataTransfer was empty